# 500 internal server error - seen in firebug

Tags: php, wordpress

From what I know, a 500 error means the server has problems accessing the given URL. I have a domain, let's call it domain.org, and I have a bunch of AJAX calls on this domain which used to work, but they stopped working all of a sudden this morning without my changing anything in the code.

That was weird but what is weirder, when I turned on Firebug, it keeps showing a 500 error for the URL I'm currently visiting.

So if I have the URL www.subdomain.domain.org/product.php open, it will show NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://subdomain.domain.org/product.php which is very confusing for me, since the page opens properly, all the content is there, and there are no other errors reported on the page.

So, I assume some server setting was changed - can someone tell me what this setting could be, or which configuration files to look at? The site is built on Smarty and, again, there were no 500 error yesterday, they just appeared today for no apparent reason. Should I just contact my hosting provider with this?

I know the question is broad, but I don't know how to specify it further since this goes against my understanding of this error.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1/

Comment: Error 500 means an an error occurred while executing the server-side code.  Have a look into the server logs: there will be more information.

Comment: Are you passing any paramter via GET or POST to the URL via AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

This class of codes are used to indicate a server failure while processing the request. It means error in your server side coding . If everything is perfect at your coding side then please visit below link

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/http-error-500-internal-server-for-php-pages-and-solution.html

Comment: but it's not fix... plz help me

Comment: @ratneshwar : Please verify whether it is server configuration related problem or your coding related problem.

Comment: I think problem in your product.php please debug your code top to bottom step-by-step using die or exit. Hopefully it will helps to find out the problem..

Comment: ok.. frndz.. but i nedd your help in my wordpress blog page where same error encounter.. http://www.poshfloors.com/blog/marble-facts-and-cleaning-tips/